# deja-dup for backups, Ubuntu One for file sync - question on plans

Tags: ubuntu-one, deja-dup

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, so asking. I often forget to back up my laptop. USB drive not connected, or doing something else, or....    So, I decided to synch to Ubuntu One.

On reading up, however, it looks like I want to go into Settings, enable backups, and backup once weekly to Ubuntu One. I did so, and am happily backing up - knowing I WILL toast a harddrive or decide to format and go again. So - deja-dup is for backups, and I do this in settings, and if my /home directory is bigger than 5 Gigs, I should pop for the 20 Gig increment? Or are backups priced differently?

My mobile phone does not have a data plan. I use it as an MP3 player, and manage it with Banshee. So I just use Banshee and a USB cord to sync music. My 5 Gigs and 1800 or so MP3's don't need to be synched. If I wanted to, though - I might consider synching my Documents and Pictures directories. But I'm not really synching to any other devices, so I'm really only keeping an online folder mirroring my laptop folders, right?

So, even if I'm only synching a Gig or so of data, I might need to pop for the 20 Gig increment if I want to backup my home directory weekly, right?

Comment: Well, I can at least state that I needed to pop for extra space to cover backups. /home came out to 11.4 Gigs. I'm thinking I don't really need synch, as I wouldn't be syncing to other devices at the moment (several PC's in the house, but we do not share documents), and have no intention of online music streaming. Sorry for posting a question I could have answered myself.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, just to be clear, syncing is good for:

- Quick access on other devices to the same files
- Easy synchronization of changes to other devices
- Disaster recovery if all you need is the latest version of the file

But it is not good for:

- Rolling back to previous versions of the file
- Getting the file back if you accidentally delete it

And for backup, just flip the good/bad points.  It's bad for quick access, but good for disaster recovery where you need older versions.

Deja Dup is makes it easy to backup all your application configuration.  Whereas with Ubuntu One, you'd have to mark a bunch of hidden folders as 'syncable'.  But that's a small point, since configuration is easily-reproduced if you had to.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That helped me see where synching would come in to play at my house. My youngest son does online highschool. He is in his 5th year (did online school for 6th through 10th so far). We check his homework, essays and papers  before he submits them. We could synch the homework directory to keep it current across our network. Now to see if this would work in a Win7, OSX Lion, Ubuntu 11.10 environment (we sure don't standardize!)